# Entity Framework database-first approach - how to make async method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, task-parallel-library

I am generating method from stored procedure using Entity Framework with a database-first approach (like below).

```
public virtual ObjectResult<GetPersons_Result> GetPersons(Nullable<int> id)
{
    var idParameter = id.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("id", id) :
            new ObjectParameter("id", typeof(int));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<GetPersons_Result>("GetPersons", idParameter);
}
```

To make this run in asynchronous way, I wrapped this method in `Task.Run()` (like below)

```
public async Task<object> GetPersons(int id)
{
    IList<GetPersons_Result> persons;

    using (var context = new PersonEntities())
    {
         persons = await Task.Run(() => 
                        context.GetPersons(id).SingleOrDefault());
    }

    return persons;
}
```

Do we have any other options to make async call for this EF generated method?.

Comment: @JSteward I've already read this thread it's asking to change auto generated code which is generated from entity framework. Then whenever we are updating procedure (adding/removing parameters) generated method will.be modified. Thats y I'm creating wrapper method for this like mentioned in 2md method. Here my question is do we any alternative way instead of Task.Run( ) in wrapper method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
    public static async Task PerformDatabaseOperations()
                {
                    using (var db = new BloggingContext())
                    {
                        // Create a new blog and save it
                        db.Blogs.Add(new Blog
                        {
                            Name = "Test Blog #" + (db.Blogs.Count() + 1)
                        });
                        Console.WriteLine("Calling SaveChanges.");
                        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                        Console.WriteLine("SaveChanges completed.");

                        // Query for all blogs ordered by name
                        Console.WriteLine("Executing query.");
                        var blogs = await (from b in db.Blogs
                                    orderby b.Name
                                    select b).ToListAsync();

                        // Write all blogs out to Console
                        Console.WriteLine("Query completed with following results:");
                        foreach (var blog in blogs)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(" - " + blog.Name);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: this is not solution for my case. Here my question is do we any alternative way instead of Task.Run( ) in wrapper method?

Comment: in above example you're not using forcefully ```Task.Run()```. This is the recommended method to use ```async``` call in ef methods. Please read the article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/async

Comment: @user1928165 I request you to give this answer useful or mark it as answer. Appreciated